# VS Code Pylance works slow with much delay

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pylance

When I try to use the autocomplete using `Pylance` it is stuck there for some time

and After Some time like 3 ~ 5 seconds the pop up with auto-complete shows up

Python Language Server is already set to `Pylance`

What I've tried so far.

Reinstall Python Extension.

Reinstall VS Code

Restarted Python Language Server

Reset VS Code

Reinstall Pylance.

**But None of the above seems to work**

Comment: You can find tons of similar reports https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues so be patient.

Comment: Could you attach the codes instead of the picture? That will be helpful to test locally.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Added the codes for this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works well on my computer, how do you open this python file?

Try moving your code to its own folder and opening that up instead of opening up some big folder that contains a lot of files. This does show a performance hole where large workspaces take a while to load.

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1338) for more details.

Comment: my workspace also contained the virtualenv and seems like it was causing the issue.. 
now after opening the folder directly solved it!!!! Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer, but it didn't solve my problem.

I also did a [complete uninstall](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall#_clean-uninstall) of VSCode and removed all its extensions and settings, but nothing changed. The IntelliSense was still stuck on `loading...` as shown below.

[image]

The only thing that worked for me was to `Install another version` of the extension, until I found one that worked (in my case v2023.9.10). I checked several times that updating to the latest version (currently v2023.10.10) caused the problem again, while installing v2023.9.10 fixed it.

[image]

I may try again in a while to see whether they fix the bug. In the meantime I will keep working with the slightly earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Scope your working directory to something smaller, it'll work much more smoothly.

Comment: Please share more details about how to do this. A good explanation helps others to learn from your answer